# Export a CMake project into Catkin(ROS)

Tags: ros, c++, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i had a library compiled with cMake , and a .cpp executable that use this library. The building and running is made without the use of catkin or ros architecture.
I would like to import this project in a ros package in order to use it to take data and publish them through a node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218040/export-a-cmake-project-into-catkin(ros)/) by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you pose a specific question?

As for how to create package, try http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

You should be able to make additions to your existing CMakeLists.txt file to add support for building with ROS.
Consult http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt

If you want to provide the capability to build with and without ROS in the same CMakeLists.txt, try switching based on the definition of `CATKIN_ENV`, e.g.,

```
if (CATKIN_ENV)
  message (STATUS "Building for ROS")
  # ...
else (CATKIN_ENV)
  message (STATUS "Building without catkin")
  # ...
endif (CATKIN_ENV)
```

---

Originally posted by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) with karma: 254 on 2015-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0